# sqlite in android- the table filled not correcty

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a wired problem.
I write a code which use sqlite. This is the relevant lines:

```
  private final String DB_NAME = "cus";
    private final String TABLE_NAME = "cus2";
    SQLiteDatabase customersDB2 = null;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private void mFillDbsTable(){
        try {
            customersDB2.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " Values ( 1, 'the ', 'ה- ');");
            customersDB2.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " Values ( 2, 'of ', 'של ');");
            customersDB2.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " Values ( 3, 'to ', 'אל ');");
            customersDB2.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " Values ( 4, 'and ', 'ו - ');");
            customersDB2.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " Values ( 5, 'a ', 'מופיע לפני שם עצם ביחיד ללא הא הידיעה ');");
            customersDB2.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " Values ( 6, 'in ', 'בתוך ');");
            customersDB2.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " Values ( 7, 'for ', 'עבור ');");
    ................
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_learn);
        try {
            customersDB2 =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(  DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            customersDB2.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " +
                    TABLE_NAME +
                    " (Block INT," +
                    " Name VARCHAR, Street VARCHAR);");
            mFillDbsTable();
}catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "create/Open the database problem");
}
```

Now, when I ask query:

```
    correctAnswer=oneTOfour.nextInt(4);
    Toast.makeText(this,"correctAnswerק"+correctAnswer,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    correctAnswerTHE_ANSWER =(r.nextInt(1000)) + 1;
    Toast.makeText(this,"correctAnswerTHE_ANSWER"+correctAnswerTHE_ANSWER,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = customersDB2.rawQuery("SELECT Name, Street  FROM "    +
            TABLE_NAME +
            " where Block = 66 ", null);


    if (c != null ) { //true

         Toast.makeText(this,"c.getColumnIndex(Name)" + c.getColumnIndex("Name"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //got 0!!
         if  (c.moveToFirst()) {   
            do {

                 name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
                 street = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Street"));          
                 results.add(name + ", " + street );
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    else{
         Toast.makeText(this,"null2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    question.setText(name);  //this is null
```

}

**It don't reach the second if**

Maybe I first ran this app with 2 column only.
I have tried to open other project, to change the name of the table..nothing work.
Some ideas?

Comment: can we see the table creation code?

Comment: What are you doing in your `mFillDbsTable` catch{} statement?

Comment: 0 IS good, it means the column "Name" is at column zero. In your select statement, you selected it first "Select Name, Street ..."

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT Name, Street  FROM " ...
```

When you name fields you want to select, it returns them in that order, so `Name` *is* the first column, or `0`.

If you want them in the order you created them, try `SELECT * FROM` instead.

The question is, what does it matter what order they're in? You're using `c.getColumnIndex()` already, so their order is not meaningful.

Comment: OK , I understand my understand's mistake.
But this is what cause the problem that sometimes the street is null and sometimes the street is it value? (and the same about "name")

Answer (score 0):

Probably related to the UTF non-stardandard characters you have in your inserts. You should try inserting using ContentValues like:

```
ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
row.put("Name", "blah");
row.put("Street", "your utf strings");
row.put("Block", 1);
long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, row);
```

Comment: but it even don't insert to the second if:


       if (c != null ) { //true
  
    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {  //false
    do {
      Toast.makeText(this,"c.getColumnIndex(Block)" + c.getColumnIndex("Block"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //got 0!!
      Toast.makeText(this,"c.getColumnIndex(Name)" + c.getColumnIndex("Name"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //got 0!!
      name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
      street = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Street"));   
         results.add(name + ", " + street );
    }while (c.moveToNext());
   }
  }